# JS Script execution order on displaying from cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am writing a rail app making trees, with bootstrap and jsPlumb.

I have this problem, when displaying a page for the first time, everything works perfectly. When I go again on a page, some code is not properly executed.
This happens with both jsPlumb and bootstrap-tagsinput: a simple tagsinput on a page is not displaying properly.
If I hit refresh, then the page loads properly again.

I tend to think this is related to the fact that when I display a page with some cached elements, some of the script are not executed, or are executed in the wrong order, but I have no clue about it, since I can't see any error.

Hence the questions,:

- How can I check that everything is properly executed (i used the console.log, the function are called)?
- Is there anything to know about the way the cache may have an effect on script?
- How can I debug this type of problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, this was due to turbolinks, which handles some of the caching on the server-side. It was a holdover gem that I suppressed, and the problem is gone.